# PDO fetch() returning one row, and PDO fetchAll() returning troubleshooting

Tags: php, database, pdo, fetch, account

I am attempting to add a query that joins two tables where their 'id(s)' are equal to one another, and from there I am wanting to display information from the two. (The first table being 'sign_in' consisting of basic account credentials, and the second being 'account' containing the user's personal information)

The example below seems to only display information from the first row, but does not return anything further.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$information = $db_connection->prepare(
    "SELECT sign_in.id, sign_in.username, sign_in.email_address, account.id, account.first_name, account.last_name
    FROM sign_in
    INNER JOIN account
    WHERE sign_in.id = account.id"
);

$information->execute(array(
    'id' => $id
));

$userRow = $information->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns all rows and the specified information; however, when trying to get the associated account information(username, email address, etc), nothing is returned.

For example, `var_dump($userRow['first_name']); die;` returns NULL.

Any explanation or help is greatly appreciated.

**Example database structure:**

[image]

[image]

**After running the query:**

[image]

Comment: Try execute with out id as argument and var_dump the result, if still you got same var_dump your query.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using **`$id`** in your query. In the code below I use a regular placeholder **`?`** as they are simpler to use.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$information = $db_connection->prepare(
    "SELECT sign_in.id, sign_in.username, sign_in.email_address, account.id, account.first_name, account.last_name
    FROM sign_in
    INNER JOIN account
    WHERE sign_in.id = ?"
);

$information->execute(array(
    'id' => $id
));

$userRow = $information->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```